# why i am getting segmentation fault error while calling this function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

Below function receives two arguments one is 'magazine' which contains strings and other is 'note' which also contains note. If 'magazine' contains all the 'note' strings the we have to print **Yes** else **No**.

```
void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazine, vector<string> note) {

    map<string, int> m;
    int n = magazine.size();

    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        if(m.find(magazine[i]) == m.end())
            m[magazine[i]] = 1;
        else
        m[magazine[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(m.find(note[i])==m.end()){
           cout<<"No"<<endl;
           return;
        }
        else{
            m[note[i]]--;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). e.g. how are you calling this function? The code depends on `notes` being at least as large as `magazine`.

Comment: If the size of notes is different ..

Comment: Because n is size of magazine and when size of magazine is greater than size of notes it is throwing exception. Second for loop should check till length of notes.

Comment: The first loop body could just be `m[magazine[i]]++;` , unkonwn entries default to 0

Comment: got it, there should be `n = note.size();` just before 2nd for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my correct code after refining the errors:

```
void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazine, vector<string> note) {

    map<string, int> m;
    int n = magazine.size();

    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        if(m.find(magazine[i]) == m.end())
            m[magazine[i]] = 1;
        else
            m[magazine[i]]++;
    }

    n = note.size();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(m.find(note[i]) == m.end() || m[note[i]] == 0){
           cout<<"No"<<endl;
           return;
        }
        else{
            m[note[i]]--;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be initializing *"n"* to be size of *"notes"* just before starting second loop.
Still to get the solution right you would need to update *"if(m.find(note[i])==m.end()){"* to *"if(m.find(note[i])==m.end() || m[note[i]] == 0){"*